# Sum of normally distributed random variables / moment generating functions

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

I consider n independent random variables with $X_1$ ~ $ N(\mu_1, \sigma_1^2)......,$ $X_n$ ~ $ N(\mu_n, \sigma_n^2$) 
I want to show that, $ \sum_{i=1}^n a_i X_i +b$~$ N(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i X_i+b, \sum_{i=1}^n a^2_i X_i )$

Using moment-generating functions I can show that $X_1+X_2 $ ~ $N(\mu_1+\mu_2, \sigma_1^2 +\sigma_2^2) $  and $M_{X_1+X_2}(t) = exp(\mu_1+\mu_2)t + \frac{(\sigma_1^2 +\sigma_2^2) \cdot t}{2}) $

Can I use this to prove my problem above?

Comment: Yes, you can show the result by induction. The constant $b$ part you either treat it as $N(b, 0)$, or just do a little extra work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to show that

$$\sum_{i=1}a_iX_i+b \sim N(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\color{red}\mu_i +b, \sum_{i=1}^na_i^2\color{red}\sigma_i^2)$$

Guide:

- Show that $a_iX_i \sim N(a_i\mu_i, a_i^2\sigma^2)$, possibly by using mgf.
- Show that $X_1+X_2 \sim N(\mu_1+\mu_2, \sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2)$. That is the sum of two independent normal is normal with the mean being the sum of the mean, and the variance being the sum of the variance.
- Now, you can use induction to prove that.

Comment: I know that $M_Z(t)= exp(\frac{t^2}{2})$ Then $$  \frac {a_iX_i - a_i \mu_i }{a_i  \sigma_i} =  \frac {X_i - \mu_i }{ \sigma_i} :=Z $$ ~$ N(0,1)  Then:$$ M_X(t)= E[exp( \sigma_i z + \mu )t) = exp(\mu_i t) M_Z(\sigma_i t) = exp(\mu_i t + \frac{\sigma_i^2 t^2}{2})$$

Comment: There is no $a_i$. Where is my mistake?

Comment: $a_iX_i - = a_i (\sigma_i Z+\mu_i)$. Hence $M_{a_iX_i}=\exp(a_i\mu_it) M_Z(a_i\sigma_it)$

Comment: Ok I see.  Then I can conclude that $a_iX_i$ ~ $N(a_i \mu_i, a_i^2) \sigma_i^2$ $M'(0)=a_i \mu_i$

Comment: Can you explain, where my mistake is? Why does $a_i$ cancel out?

Comment: You compute $M_X$ but we are interested in $M_{aX}$.

Comment: Silly mistake:( What can I do with the b-term. When I consider $X$~ N(b,0), then I would get my result?

Comment: yup, you can do that or work on $M_{X+b}$ to show that only the mean get translated.

Comment: Thank you very much:)